# How to merge these results into one row

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have this code below. I am trying to merge the rows based on date.

```
SELECT

TICKETS.TICKETID,
RECEIPTS.DATENEW,
TAXCATEGORIES.NAME = 'GCT' as GCT,
TAXCATEGORIES.NAME = 'Tax 25%' as Tax25,
TAXLINES.AMOUNT,

SUM(TAXLINES.AMOUNT) AS TOTAL,
SUM(CASE WHEN taxcategories.NAME = 'GCT' THEN taxlines.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS GCTTOTAL,
SUM(CASE WHEN taxcategories.NAME = 'Tax 25%' THEN taxlines.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS TAX25TOTAL

   FROM
     RECEIPTS,
     TAXLINES,
     TAXES,
     TAXCATEGORIES,
     TICKETS,
     PAYMENTS

  WHERE
    PAYMENTS.RECEIPT = RECEIPTS.ID
    AND RECEIPTS.ID = TAXLINES.RECEIPT
    AND RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID
    AND TAXLINES.TAXID = TAXES.ID
    AND TAXES.CATEGORY = TAXCATEGORIES.ID
    AND DATENEW >= '2016-07-14 00:00:00' AND DATENEW <= '2016-07-14 23:00:00'


GROUP BY gct, Tax25, CAST(RECEIPTS.DATENEW AS DATE)
```

The Result of the query is attached in the screenshot below:
[image]

Now I need help to merge those rows that have the same date into one row. I am not sure where I am going wrong, I've tried a series of joins but I'm coming up blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the records with the same date actually differ in their values for the `GCT` and `Tax25` columns.  If you remove these columns from the `GROUP BY` clause, and instead aggregate them in the `SELECT` list, you would be left with a single record for the duplicate dates.

Note that in the query below I have replaced your implicit joins (using a comma-separated list of tables in the `FROM` clause) with explicit inner joins, with the join criteria in the `ON` clause.  This is the standard way of writing queries now, and it makes them much easier to read.  If `INNER JOIN` is too restrictive, then perhaps you intended to use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT TICKETS.TICKETID,
       RECEIPTS.DATENEW,
       MAX(TAXCATEGORIES.NAME) = 'GCT' as GCT,         -- one value per date
       MAX(TAXCATEGORIES.NAME) = 'Tax 25%' as Tax25,   -- one value per date
       TAXLINES.AMOUNT,
       SUM(TAXLINES.AMOUNT) AS TOTAL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN taxcategories.NAME = 'GCT' THEN taxlines.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS GCTTOTAL,
       SUM(CASE WHEN taxcategories.NAME = 'Tax 25%' THEN taxlines.AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) AS TAX25TOTAL
FROM RECEIPTS
INNER JOIN TAXLINES
    ON RECEIPTS.ID = TAXLINES.RECEIPT
INNER JOIN TAXES
    ON TAXLINES.TAXID = TAXES.ID
INNER JOIN TAXCATEGORIES
    ON TAXES.CATEGORY = TAXCATEGORIES.ID
INNER JOIN TICKETS
    ON RECEIPTS.ID = TICKETS.ID
INNER JOIN PAYMENTS
    ON PAYMENTS.RECEIPT = RECEIPTS.ID
WHERE DATENEW >= '2016-07-14 00:00:00' AND
      DATENEW <= '2016-07-14 23:00:00'
GROUP BY CAST(RECEIPTS.DATENEW AS DATE)
```

Comment: This is absolutely PERFECT. Thank You @tim-biegeleisen

Comment: @RobertFarr Happy to help you out.